# Android String if use

Tags: android, string, if-statement

```
TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postOutput);
    String x = text.getText().toString();
    String y = "hata";
    if (y.equalsIgnoreCase(x)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
    System.out.println ("x= "+x);
    System.out.println ("y= "+y);
```

Logcat:

```
I/System.out: x= hata
I/System.out: y= hata
```

**Toast doesn't appear**

Comment: there is an error
the code doesn't work

Comment: You will have to tell us what is the error.

Comment: no error but Toast  doesn't work

Comment: try to verify that the String x is indeed equal to "hata", that might be the problem.

Comment: You maybe type Hata. Java is case sensitive  try with equalsIgnoreCase(x)

Comment: May be `x` has uppercase in the string. In that case use `equalIgnoreCase()`

Comment: caps have the problem

Comment: http://prntscr.com/9wzv33

Comment: Please give the full source code.

Comment: @HuskyHuskie `  TextView text = (TextView)findViewById(R.id.postOutput);
        String x = text.getText().toString();
        if (x.equalsIgnoreCase("hata")){
            System.out.println("HERE");
        }
        System.out.println ("x= "+x);`

Logcat :I/System.out: x= hata
"no System.out.println("HERE");"

Comment: That's not the full source code. Good luck.

Comment: @HuskyHuskie skype add pls "0mh3r@hotmail.com.tr"

Comment: Comment out the if statement and see if the Toast will display properly.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe your x value contains space.

Try:

```
String x = text.getText().toString().trim();
```

Answer (score 0):

If there is no error and the Toast simply isn't showing up then it's possible that the String x is not equal to `"hata"`.

Try to verify that the String x is indeed equal to `"hata"` with `System.out.println(x);` and check the console output of your app.

Comment: here :01-31 00:39:54.197 19334-19334/? I/System.out: hata

Answer (score 0):

You are comparing the string and the `TextView` properly, the only cause I can imagine is that the `TextView` contents another text than "**hata**"

try with

```
if ("hata".equalIgnoreCase(x)){
        Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "hata", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
  }
```

or even better print in the console the value of the string, so you can verify it when debugging.